# Trying to get nginx to return 301, preserving $_GET

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I'm having trouble configuring nginx to return the url I want. I'd like `http://domain.com/blah?abc=e9800ecf8` to return `http://domain.com/createpage.php?abc=e9800ecf8`, i.e. it preserves the `abc` variable in `$_GET`

`createpage.php` is sitting in /www/webroot, and `blah` doesn't exist. How do I do this?

Here's my server block of the config file (obviously, not doing what I want):

```
server {
    root /www/webroot;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
    location = /blah {
      return 301 /createpage.php;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {

    root /www/webroot;
    index index.html;

    location / {

        if ($request_uri ~ "^/blah\?abc=([a-z0-9]+)$") {
            return 301 /createpage.php?abc=$1;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I presume you meant `[a-z0-9]` ? It's still giving 404s after loading the configuration file, even if I just try to `return 301 index.html`.

Comment: @Escher Yes. What does your error log says ? `index.html` is not a valid URI. Btw, is it your only server block ? Because if not you need to define the `server_name` directive according to your domain.

Comment: Error log is empty. Access log is `127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2015:00:10:26 +0100] "GET /blah?abc=a1723 HTTP/1.1" 404 177 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
` i.e. you can see that I'm testing it on a small test server before it goes on the production one (so server_name is not needed for the moment; I'm trying to have the simplest config file possible to isolate the problem. You're right about the URI, I changed it to `/` and it loads the index page as intended.

Comment: @Escher Well there's no point it would not work except if the `server_name` directive doesn't match because you have more than one server block loaded by your configuration or you did not reload nginx or you are have typos somewhere.

Comment: Found the error as I was commenting out line by lin: something in  `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` was interfering. The 301 return works, however it just shows me my php code, rather than passing it through the PHP interpreter module. I guess I need to work on the PHP FPM block now. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: All working now; I had clumsily commented out a brace (it's too late at night to be doing this sort of thing!)